# Python SocksiPy package error: TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API for string?

Tags: python, socks, imaplib

When i try and connect to gmail through this code:

```
import socks
import imaplib
import socket
import socks
s = socks.socksocket()
s.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, '192.168.208.51', 3128)
s.connect(('imap.gmail.com', 993))
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
s.connect(('imap.gmail.com', 993))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 406, in connect
self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0],destpair[1])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 357, in __negotiatehttp
while resp.find("\r\n\r\n")==-1:
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Any ideas? Im on a computer that uses a proxy hence using SocksiPy to connect to imap.gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code; you are using a version of SocksiPy that has not been ported to Python 3. You should upgrade to version 1.02. Or you should switch back to Python 2.

---

**Explaination:**

This is Python 3. Unlike Python 2, `bytes` and `str` objects are not interchangeable. If you try to do stuff like this:

```
>>> b'abc'.find('a')
```

You'll get the error you are seeing. In fact, the "buffer API" is the one implemented by `bytes` objects.

Comment: How do i upgrade? Im using windows?

Comment: @SteMain: it appears this version is only available on Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives. If I were you, I'd [download](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/188360484/python3-socksipy_1.02-2_all.deb) the Ubuntu package, extract it and copy the `socks.py` file to `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages`.

Comment: Arw thats a real pain in the... because all my code is for Python34 on windows :(

Comment: @SteMain: it's packaged for Debian/Ubuntu, but it will work on Windows. Just download, extract and copy it.

Comment: I have edited my question with the new error. Thanks for your help mate

Comment: @SteMain: that error has to do with your proxy, not with SocksiPy. Please restore your question and create a new one. (This is how Stack Overflow works.)